# How to generate connected nodes in AWS X-Ray?

Tags: aws-xray

I'm new to Amazon X-Ray and have gone through the documentation. I have understood the flow of my code and how different code segments link with each other. But when I create new segments, I'm not able to link them and they are being displayed individually.

In the documentation there is a parameter called `trace id` which can be given when a new segment is created but I'm not sure what the format for the `trace id` is?

Can some please explain how to link multiple segments to a single client and also the links between the segments?

[How my current service graph looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdwQK.png)

[What I want my service graph to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nk8B.png)

Answer (score 0):

There should be only one `Segment` in each service and all of its internal business logics or downstream calls should be treated as `Subsegment`s. All of these trace components along a single request share the same trace id so that you can see a tree-like service graph with connected nodes. We do provide instrumented libraries for you to create/connect `Segment` and `Subsegment` created within application and seems like you're creating `Segment` for each component in your application with individual trace id. May I know which language you're using?